# (PHP, MySQL) Where is this documented

Tags: php, mysql

I tried different search queries to find the source of the documentation of this. What is this 'e', and where is this documented?

In PHP:

```
echo 2e2 --> 200
echo 2e0 --> 2
```

In MYSQL:

```
select 2e2 --> 200
select 2e0 --> 2
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 1):

The E means Engineering notation.

For example 2E2 = 2 * 10 ^ 2
Aother example 2E13 = 2 * 10 ^ 13

it's another style to display tens of magnitude